# Prove that the following language is not a context-free

Tags: context-free-language, pumping-lemma

L = {a^i b^j c^k; i≠j and i≠k and j≠k}.

First approach: I tried two different string to prove it by pumping lemma but non of them is correct.
first w = a^m b^m+1 c^m+2 and m is pumping length. for example one case in 
w = uvxyz is that vxy in is a part. so w = a^m-k a^k b^m+1 c^m+2 for any i >=0 it has to be in the L wi = a^m-k a^ik b^m+1 c^m+2. I cant show that number of a's is equal to number of b's.

Second approach: I converted L into union of 6 different languages {a^ib^jc^k U a^ib^kc^j  U a^jb^ic^k  U a^jb^kc^i  U a^kb^ic^j  U a^kb^jc^i  ; i

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

If we pick W= a^m! b^(m+1)! c^(m+2)! then we can prove it.

I am solving for the case that uxy is in a's side. then 
W= a^m!-k a^k b^(m+1)! c(m+2)! we know that there exist an integer x = m! m / k for 1<= k <= m so we pick i = (1+x) then m! + k x = m! + m! m = m! (m+1) = (m+1)! means the number of a’s = number of b’s which means this string is not in L. This is a contradiction.

Comment: why can't you pick vxy = ccc ?

Answer (score 0):

Ogden's lemma is your friend.

Choose w = a^{m!}b^{2m!}c^{3m!} and mark the a's.

If v or y contained more than one type of letter then
u v^2 x y^2 z would not be in the correct order.

Since vy must contain a's (marked), vy must omit either b's or c's (or both). Assume vy contained exactly k a's. If vy omits b's, let p = m!/k + 1 which is an integer since k<m. Consider
u v^p x y^p z. This has 2m! a's and 2m! b's. Similarly for the case of vy omitting c's, let p=2m!/k +1 and the pumped word has 3m! a's and 3m! c's.